Difference between greek Δ "delta" letter buffers "ce 94" and "e2 88 86"
I'm reading content with decomposed UTF-8, where I get the buffer "e2 88 86" for the greek Δ "delta" letter.
When I search the "Δ" letter in this content, I found nothing.
But when I build a string with "Δ" picked from wikipedia or whatever, I obtain the buffer "ce 94", and now I can find "Δ".
Is there a way to obtain the "ce 94" buffer from "e2 88 86" ?
I tried to normalize the content, but nothing changed.

Compatibility normalizations (so with K should change it. (OTOH they are not canonical, and so not taken too easily, but for certain scopes)

Those are different characters. From Unicode database (column CodePoint contains Unicode (U+hhhh) and UTF-8 bytes):
Char CodePoint                     Category Description
---- ---------                     -------- -----------
   Δ {U+0394, \xCE\x94}     UppercaseLetter Greek Capital Letter Delta
   ∆ {U+2206, \xE2\x88\x86}      MathSymbol Increment

